# Direct Clang to not generate dependencies on specific header or directory

Tags: c++, optimization, header, dependencies, clang

I have a giant list of type-ids in a header file 'type_id.h' that are generated from a pre-build step that parses source files, looking for typenames annotated with specific #define macros:

```
MAKE_TYPE_ID class MyCustomClass
{
};

MAKE_TYPE_ID class MyOtherClass
{
};
```

This generates a header file like this:

```
#pragma once

template<class T>
unsigned long TypeId() { static_assert( false, "unknown type" ); return 0; }
  
template<>
unsigned long TypeId<MyOtherClass>() { return 0xfeedfeed; } // actually the hash of 'MyOtherClass'

template<>
unsigned long TypeId<MyCustomClass>() { return 0xfadefade; } // actually the hash of 'MyCustomClass'

... and so on
```

Every time someone on my team modifies one of the source files the header is regenerated, and if it has changed from the previous iteration, it is copied overtop so the source code can see any new type_ids. This causes a cascade of everything that includes "type_id.h". However, the values in the header file are mutually exclusive and accessed via a template specialization. Further, to call TypeId the client code has to include "MyCustomClass.h", so there is a dependency already on the type.

**I am trying to avoid having Clang depend on the type_id.h header all together** -- that is, I want to be able to regenerate the header without having all the other files compile. I have had this working in the past in Visual Studio by putting my header in the 'Exclude Directories' list, but I cannot find something comprable in Clang/LLVM.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how this could be accomplished? As work arounds I have thought about explicit specialization of TypeId<> inside a .cpp, which works, but unfortunately I use the default case to static assert on TypeId<> being called on an unsupported type (not all scanned types are included in TypeId<>). Without the default implementation of TypeId<> with a static assert, I have to rely on unresolved external linker errors, which is not verbose or clear to some users.

Comment: Have you tried fooling your build system by changing the file creation/modification timestamp to a date in the past? Of course that will not work if your build system looks at file hashes..